# why is click function not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

//html

```
 <form name="userupdateaboutform" class="userupdateaboutclass" id="userupdateaboutformid">
       <textarea type="text" class="updateaboutusclass" name="aboutus" placeholder="About Us"  ></textarea><br>    
          <button name="updateabout" class="btn btn-primary" id="updateaboutid">update</button> 
      </form>
```

//script

```
  var btnupdtabout = document.getElementById('updateaboutid');
    if(btnupdtabout){
        btnupdtabout.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      
              console.log(e);
            
          })
    }
```

can't see the error even i used the logs all i see is that 'uncaught' error message since the function leaves so fast, what im trying to do here is when i click the button the modal will pop up. but it is not functioning properly

Comment: It might be because your `<button>` is inside a `<form>` which when a button with `type="submit"` will submit the form, since you didn't provide the `type` attribute, this might submit the form as well. You can try adding `type="button"` attribute to your button to prevent it.

Comment: You can use ` onsubmit="return validateForm()"` attr for `form`